# 301 redirect with multiple domain names in .htacess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a 301 redirect for some domains that I have. I have multiple domains pointing to my main domain.

I am currently using the following code to re-direct one domain. However what is the best way to point multiple domains to the same main domain?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain-name.me.uk [NC]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is this the correct way to do multiple domains?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain-name.me.uk [NC]
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain-name.digital [NC]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Replace `[NC]` with `[NC,OR]`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using negation based condition to avoid matching multiple host names and avoiding multiple conditions.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?main-domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.main-domain.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?main-domain\.co\.uk$` will make sure to redirect when current request is not for `www.main-domain.co.uk`.